# How to redirect onr domain (with local folder language) to two domains?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I had domain:

exa.mple -> Dutch version
exa.mple/en -> English Versiom

**Now I have**

example.nl
example.com

I would like to redirect all urls from exa.mple/en to example.com/$
And exa.mple to example.nl

**I have this code:**

```
#exa.mple/en to .com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exa.mple/en$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exa.mple/en$
RewriteRule (.*)$ "https://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]

#exa.mple to .nl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exa.mple$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exa.mple$
RewriteRule (.*)$ "https://example.nl/$1" [R=301,L]
```

But problem there is if I have this website:

https://exa.mple/en/contact

Then I get:
https://example.nl/en/contact

Somone could help me with it how can avoid if URL contains /en/ to redirect to NL domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this code and everything works ok:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exa.mple$
RewriteRule ^(?!en)(.*)$ https://example.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

#ex.mple.com/en to .com
RewriteCond ℅{HTTP_HOST} ^exa.mple$
RewriteRule ^en.*$ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
#exa.mple.com/ to .nl
RewriteCond ℅{HTTP_HOST} ^exa.mple$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

The second rule redirects all requests from `exa.pmle` to `example.nl` . If you want to redirect just the homepage then simply change the regex pattern to `^$` .

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing these new rules.

Comment: Hello @starkeen, thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, your solution does not work. Even it does not redirect `exa.mple/en/contact` to `example.com/contact`.